# How many structurally different latin squares of order 5 do exist?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know the number of latin squares order 5 which start with 1 2 3 4 5 in the 1st row or column, that is 1344, but the greater part of that number consists of structural duplicates of each other. So, I mean the number of latin squares, order 5, which cannot be made identical by means of rotation, reflection, or permutation of the symbols. (In order 4, the equivalent number is 12).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $192$. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/9503acd55f37e7e30d66) to compute it. The corresponding number for order $6$ is $145164$.

Somewhat surprisingly, the sequence $12$, $192$, $145164$ isn't in OEIS; in fact there seems to be no sequence at all related to Latin squares and reflections and/or rotations.

By "in the 1st row or column" you seem to mean two separate but equal counts, one for fixed row, one for fixed column. The corresponding OEIS sequence is [A000479](https://oeis.org/A000479). OEIS sequence [A040082](https://oeis.org/A040082) contains the numbers of Latin squares equivalent under row, column and symbol permutations.

Comment: Thank you! I pointed out the number of 192 without a computerprogram, and with help of my home-made LS5 puzzle. For more info: The method is described in www.latinsquares5x5.wordpress.com .( I feel that my method will not work for LS6)

Comment: @willembarink: Well then it was rather bad style to ask the question here and not say that you already knew the answer. -1.

Comment: Anyway, you helped me a lot in finding out very fast that my scientific result  - 192 - is not unique. I am very grateful to you, please don't feel used,  accept my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

.....and in the meantime(January 2016) the sequence is in OEIS, see OEIS/A264603